# Проблемка с SQL-запросом

Tags: mysqli

Не удается подсчитать кол-во файлов в папке безграничной вложенности.

```
SELECT `share_cat`.*, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `share_files` WHERE `share_files`.`path` LIKE (`share_cat`.`path` + '%') AND `size` > '0') AS `count_files` FROM `share_cat` WHERE `refid`='0' ORDER BY `realid`
```

Нужно как-то реализовать во вложенном цикле и вывести в шаблон на Smarty.

Структура категорий

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `share_cat` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`refid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`realid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`maxfilesize` int(11) NOT NULL,
`path` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`infolder` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`uploaduser` int(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `path` (`path`),
KEY `infolder` (`infolder`),
KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8;
```

Структура файлов

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `share_files` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`refid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_tema` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`name_translate` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
`file` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`size` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`path` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`infolder` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`screen` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
`timeload` int(11) NOT NULL,
`loadcounts` int(11) NOT NULL,
`prosmotrov` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT
CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Оффтоп: Вас бы сильно спасло использование Nested Sets, которые как раз созданы для таких целей: хранение деревьев.

Comment: Еще есть варианты?

Comment: В обычном не вложенном цикле вот так LIKE '".$row['path']."%' работает

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, конечно, сложение строк не правильное, должно быть:

```
LIKE CONCAT(`share_cat`.`path`, '%')
```